# How to combine scene2d and box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, scene2d

I use box2d and want to add a few buttons on screen. I figured the easiest way to do this is to use scene2d for buttons. Is it possible to combine these two and if it is how to do it?  I'm new to box2d and all the tutorials that i have looked at don't have any examples of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, `box2d` does not depend on your scene representation. Just render your `scene2d` normally while keep calling `world.step` on each iteration.

Comment: I'm surprised that so many ppl get confused by completely different technologies, just because both of them have a "2d" in their name and that seems to make it impossible to use them together.